# virtual reality - aframe.io - watch on phone

Tags: html, localhost, aframe

I'm new to the VR developing and been trying Googles aframe.io. What is the quickest/easiest way to see 360 generated html page through my phone?
When writing the html page I run it on my laptop and run it on localhost with MAMP. how can I watch it on my phone?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with virtual reality or you simply want to open the website from your cellphone?

Comment: so I thought maybe there's a way/site that somehow turns it into QR code that you can scan with your phone

Answer (score 0):

Run a local server on your computer with the files hosted on it, then on the mobile browser, enter your IPv4 in the URL input field.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://ngrok.com/ , a service to proxy to your localhost.